# "Время спать!" Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Пожалуй, время спать!

Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое? Какой это тип предложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из толкового словаря Ожегова:
[ВРЕМЯ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/29606)
**7. в знач. сказ., c неопред.** Подходящий, удобный срок, благоприятный момент.
*Не время сидеть сложа руки. Самое время обедать.*

Получается, что *время спать* — это и есть сказуемое.
Какой тип? Тут есть сомнения. По структуре, как мне кажется, это полное предложение (т. е. у него не пропущен второй член — подлежащее не нужно для понимания смысла предложения).
Я бы посчитала это предложение односоставным, обобщённо-личным (действие может быть отнесено ко всякому лицу).

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, все сочетание является сказуемым. Ибо *"время"+<инфинитив>* - устойчивое сочетание. Сравните с *пора спать*.